# Android - When checking to see if text box length is longer or equal to 1 to then do something, it only does it if character length is 3 or more

Tags: java, android, textbox, character

```
if (checkBoxSlower.isChecked()) {
    if (editTextSF.getText().length() >= 1) {
        sf2[0] = (Integer.parseInt(editTextSF.getText().toString()));
        sf[0] = 1 + (sf2[0] / 100);
    }
    else {
        sf[0] = 1.35; // default - 1.35
    }
}
else if (checkBoxFaster.isChecked()) {
    if (editTextSF.getText().length() >= 1) {
        sf2[0] = (Integer.parseInt(editTextSF.getText().toString()));
        sf[0] = 1 - (sf2[0] / 100);
    }
    else {
        sf[0] = 0.65; // default - 0.65
    }
}
```

That's my code that i am referring to, the numbers only text box skips the if statement if it says 99 or lower, but with 100 it works, Can't find an answer online

Comment: Is this code contained within a State Changed event? One checkbox may be contradicting the other checkbox if both are selected (check marked) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working. But it seems you're not considered one logical point.
 result of this division `sf2[0] / 100` is zero if `sf2[0] < 100`. in the other hand when `editTextSF.getText().length() >= 1` and `editTextSF.getText().length() < 3` it means that your input number is between `0` to `99` that you assign it to `sf2[0]`. because of that `sf[0]` will be `1` either `checkBoxSlower.isChecked()` or `checkBoxFaster.isChecked()`

Comment: you're welcome. I would appreciate if you upvote it too :)

Comment: cant do that yet :(